# Can't Read data (payload) from non-NDEF tag

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, nfc

I'm using [Phonegap-nfc plugin](https://github.com/don/phonegap-nfc-reader)

I'm trying to read data (payload) from my non-NDEF NFC card.
the only ACTION that is triggered is **ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED** and i only can read the tag_info.

the tag's techs are **NfcB** and **IsoDep**

*nfc_tech_filter.xml*

```
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
</tech-list>
```

*NfcReader/AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

can anyone please help me get the data?

Comment: What do you expect to read if the tag does not contain an NDEF payload? What type of card is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin only supports NDEF. Android supports NfcB and IsoDep so it's possible to extend this plugin to do what i need.

Thanks to  [Don](https://github.com/don)...